# Trying to solve infinite integral involving error function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

I am trying to evaluate

$$I = \int^{\infty}_0 (y^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y})dy$$

using the fact that

$$\int^{\infty}_0 (e^{-x^2})dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Not sure how to do this. I tried transforming with $y=2x^2$ substitution, but found this suggests

$$I = \sqrt{2} \int^{\infty}_0 (xe^{-x^2})dx$$

By this point Wolfram tells me I've made a mistake as evaluating the above definite integral yields

$$I=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

which does not involve $\sqrt{\pi}$ and is surely incorrect. Any help?

Comment: Note that - formally - from the relation $y=2x^2$, by (formal) differentiation we get $dy = (2x^2)'\; dx=4x\; dx$.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} y^{1/2} e^{-y/2} dy$$
Let $y-2x^2, dy=4x dx$, then 
$$I=4 \sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-x^2} dx= 4 \sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} x. x e^{-x^2} dx$$ Integration by parts leads to 
$$I=4\sqrt{2}~ [-\frac{x}{2} e^{-x^2}|_{0}^{\infty}+\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2} dx~]$$
$$I=2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\sqrt{2\pi}$$

Answer (score 0):

When I substitute $y=2x^2$ I get
$$I=4\sqrt2\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}\,dx.$$
By integration by parts, this can be reduced to the usual "probability integral"
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx.$$